# Freeze at login screen for about 30 seconds

Tags: login, mouse

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (64 bit, Desktop) and when I start the pc, the login screen appears, i'll have to wait about 30 seconds until i can click on my username and enter my password.
The mouse cursor is not moving when moving the mouse and it does not react on keyboard inputs.

That issue appeared 2 days ago and I'm worried, that this will result in a bigger problem (though its also annoying yet).

Can someone help me with that?

Link to Reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/noji17/freeze_at_login_screen_for_about_30_seconds/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  The way I solved it was:

```
$ journalctl -f -n5000
```

Then scroll back and look at the most recent bootup sequence, find the delay where there is about 30sec between steps.  Look at the first item after the delay.

In my case the `bluez` and `fprint` daemons were loading or timing out.  Since I wasn't using them I removed them with:

```
$ sudo apt purge xxxxx
```

Hope this helps!